# Can I found order ID of Shapeshift transaction that has been made on Parity?

Tags: parity, shapeshift

I want to solve some problem with transaction on Parity that is related to Shapeshift. Is it possible to found shapeshift's order ID from a few hours ago. Is it maybe stored in the Parity's local files?

Comment: Parity does not store Shapeshift order IDs. What are you trying to do?

Comment: During shapeshifting via parity I end up sending ether on some wrong address. But I'm 99% I didn't made a typo, because I copy and paste the address from the shapeshif interface. Now I need order ID so that support can help me solve this

Comment: That's clearly no Parity address, it must be a Shapeshift address. Can't they check that address for you?

Comment: They did and tell me that address is not in their database. but maybe there is a bug in the plugin for parity. Or I was maybe hacked by some other extension in chrome. Maybe some extension switched the address on the screen.